# Microsoft.Moles.NUnit.dll with nunit 2.6

Tags: nunit, pex-and-moles

How can I make Microsoft.Moles.NUnit.dll work with nunit 2.6. The [docs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.docx) say:

> **Assembly**
>
> Microsoft.Moles.NUnit.dll  You will have to register that add-in with
>   NUnit by copying the Microsoft.Moles.NUnit.dll assembly in the NUnit
>   bin/addins folder.
>
> **NUnit Version**
>
> 2.5.2.9222 (for other NUnit versions, recompile the attribute from sources)

But where do I get the moles source from? Isure cannot recompile anything if I do not have the moles sources, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is in **moles.samples.zip** inside Documentation folder
i.e. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\Documentation" with default installation.

It is mentioned in the [docs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.docx) just above the NUnit section.

> **Other Unit Test Frameworks**
>
> It is possible to use Moles with any unit
>   test framework that supports a managed command line runner. In order
>   to execute the mole types in an instrumented process, you have to
>   launch the unit test runner through the moles.runner.exe command-line
>   tool.
>
> ...
>
> The following extensions wrap the creation of the mole type
>   context as an attribute. This makes mole types easier to use with
>   those unit test frameworks. **The full source of each attribute is
>   available in the samples that are provided in the Pex or Moles
>   installer**. This allows to recompile them against the version of the
>   test framework you are using.